# C# Console Form INPUT issue

Tags: c#, forms, api, input, console

I'm doing little console program with API (https://github.com/Hipo/university-domains-list-api), and I have an issue - when I write information into variables inputkeyword and inputcountry for the first time it works fine, but for the second and etc. times I get the same answer as I got on the first try. Thanks for help.

```
    public interface IRequestHandler
    {
        //Method to get the data of the repo provided by the url
        string GetResult(string url);
    }
    // using request handler to get an url address
    public static string GetResult(IRequestHandler requestHandler)
    {
        return requestHandler.GetResult(RequestConstants.Url);
    }

    public class RestSharpRequestHandler : IRequestHandler
    {
        public string GetResult(string url)
        {
            var client = new RestClient(url);
            var response = client.Execute(new RestRequest());
            return response.Content;
        }
    }

    public class Input
    {
        public static string userInputKeyWord;
        public static string userInputCountry;
        public static void dot()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Insert keyword which you need to find your university");
            userInputKeyWord = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You entered keyword {0}", userInputKeyWord);
            Console.WriteLine();


            Console.WriteLine("Insert country which you need");
            userInputCountry = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You entered country {0}", userInputCountry);
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Creating the list of schools according to your request.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            IRequestHandler restSharpRequestHandler = new RestSharpRequestHandler();
            var response = GetResult(restSharpRequestHandler);
            var Results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<School>>(response);
            if (Results.Count() == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nothing found.");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var release in Results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Country: {0}", release.Country);
                    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", release.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine("Domains: {0}", release.Domains);
                    Console.WriteLine();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    // JSON properties
    public class School
    {
        [JsonProperty("web_pages")]
        public Uri[] WebPages { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("alpha_two_code")]
        public string AlphaTwoCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("state-province")]
        public object StateProvince { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("country")]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("domains")]
        public string[] Domains { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    //url for getting information from json
    public class RequestConstants : Input
    {

        //public static string userInputKeyWord;
        //public static string userInputCountry;
        public string BaseUrl = "http://universities.hipolabs.com/";
        public static string Url = "http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?name=" + userInputKeyWord + "&country=" + userInputCountry + "";
        public string UserAgent = "User-Agent";
        public string UserAgentValue = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36";
    }

}

}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code you want us to debug for you.  This is a great time for *you* to begin to familiarize yourself with debugging.  Using a debugger you can place a breakpoint on any line of code to pause the runtime execution on that line.  Then you can step through the code line by line as it executes and observe the exact runtime behavior and the changing values of your variables.  When you do this, on which specific line do you first observe an unexpected result?  What were the values at that time?  What was the observed result?  What result did you expect?  Why?

Comment: Observed result is that every time I write keyword and country, I get different result - list of countries, names and domains according to my query(url). Now I get same result even if try to write keyword and country for the second time.

Comment: You missed the part about using a debugger and identifying the specific line(s) of code and the specific variable values.  That's really the important part.

Comment: I get most of issues in public static string Url = "http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?name=" + userInputKeyWord + "&country=" + userInputCountry + ""; If I don't use static I get an error in other place return requestHandler.GetResult(RequestConstants.Url);

Comment: Well, the code shown on that line shouldn't even compile.  Those variables aren't defined in that scope.  As for your issues, what are "most of issues" in this case?  What is the resulting value of `Url`?  What do you expect that value to be?  Why?

Comment: I expect that everytime  I write keyword and country I get different values of url.

Comment: Where do you update the static `Url` variable?  If you never update that variable then it will continue to have whatever value you first gave it.  Your debugging would observe this fact, and you haven't indicated otherwise.  So, again... Where specifically are you seeing a problem in your debugging?

Comment: If I delete static from  public static string Url = "http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?name=" + userInputKeyWord + "&country=" + userInputCountry + ""; then I get an error in RequestConstants.Url.    public static string GetResult(IRequestHandler requestHandler)
    {
        return requestHandler.GetResult(RequestConstants.Url);
    }

Comment: Where in the `Input.Dot()` method do you update the static variable `Url`?  Hint: You don't.  You *use* that variable in your `GetResult` method, but you never *update* its value.  So it will continue to have the same value you originally gave it.  I guess if you want to update a variable then you should update the variable.  Though I imagine you're right in saying that whatever you're doing "is not the best way".  It seems like this code is just littering the `static` keyword in random places, which is going to cause a lot of confusion if you don't understand what it means.

Comment: Though this also goes back to the concept of debugging... If you are expecting the `Url` variable to change, where in your debugging are you expecting that to happen?  Where do you observe it happening, or not happening?  You are clearly **not debugging**, which is really what you should be doing.  Observing is always preferable to guessing.  Use your debugger and *observe* exactly what your code is doing.  There's also an excellent article about some basic debugging practices you can try: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: My errors - If I delete static from  public static string Url = "http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?name=" + userInputKeyWord + "&country=" + userInputCountry + ""; then I get an error in RequestConstants.Url.    public static string GetResult(IRequestHandler requestHandler)
    {
        return requestHandler.GetResult(RequestConstants.Url);
    }                     if i delete static from this string I get an error in var response = GetResult(restSharpRequestHandler);

Comment: You are again just randomly adding/removing the `static` keyword in your program as though it is some sort of decorative garnish, and are ignoring the error messages you are receiving as a result.  This is an ineffective strategy.  Ask yourself, *should* this value be `static`?  Why should it be?  Or why shouldn't it be?  Make it whatever it *should* be, and then address any resulting errors specifically.  (Hint: If you *don't know* what `static` means then *that's probably your bug*.  Randomly writing code without knowing what it's supposed to do *will* lead to bugs.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

```
public static string Url = "http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?name=" + userInputKeyWord + "&country=" + userInputCountry + "";
```

to

```
public static string Url => "http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?name=" + userInputKeyWord + "&country=" + userInputCountry + "";
```

(notice "=" has been changed to arrow "=>")

It should work because you have declared field **Url** that is set only once. And I suggest you to turn it into a property that is calculated every time so it respects changes to that static fields. It's effectively similar to declaring a method

```
public static string GetUrl() {
    return "http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?name=" + userInputKeyWord + "&country=" + userInputCountry + "";
}
```

Also it's better to use RestSharp API to add parameters to a request. I'd update your code as following

```
public interface IRequestHandler
{
    //Method to get the data of the repo provided by the url
    string GetResult(string keyword, string country);
}
// using request handler to get an url address
public static string GetResult(IRequestHandler requestHandler, string keyword, string country)
{
    return requestHandler.GetResult(keyword, country);
}

public class RestSharpRequestHandler : IRequestHandler
{
    const string url = "http://universities.hipolabs.com/search";

    public string GetResult(string keyword, string country)
    {
        //"http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?name=" + userInputKeyWord + "&country=" + userInputCountry + "";
        //the values given in the url are GET params, so we add it using RestSharp API
        //also it's unsafe to manually concatenate parameters in url because some values should be encoded according to HTTP specification. Let RestSharp does it for you
        var client = new RestClient(url);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddParameter("name", keyword);
        request.AddParameter("country", country);
        var response = client.Execute(request);
        return response.Content;
    }
}
```

And line

```
var response = GetResult(restSharpRequestHandler);
```

Will turn into

```
var response = GetResult(restSharpRequestHandler, userInputKeyWord, userInputCountry);
```

Comment: I've updated my post a bit. Hope it will help you to improve your code.

Comment: I saw it, thank you.